# MythBuntu in VirtualBox with HDHomeRun Prime and Xfinity

Tags: virtualbox, mythbuntu, mythtv

Over the last week, I have installed about a half-dozen different Ubuntu/MythTV configurations in VirtualBox.  Today I tried MythBuntu, but I keep getting the same results.

When I try to tune to any channel I only get (TL__) Partial Lock...95% on the lower channels down to 25% farther up.

Is the HDHomeRun Prime supported to Xfinity(Comcast) on MythBuntu?  I have been using my HDHomeRun Prime with WMC and HDHomeRun View for several years, so I know my cablecard setup is working properly.

I have uploaded my log files to [MythBuntu Logs](http://pastebin.com/sVLWn9XL).

I believe I have followed the setup instructions faithfully, but if my configuration is supported, then I must be doing something wrong.

Can someone please check out my logs and tell me what I need to change?  Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

TIA...Chuck

Comment: You should edit your post and add the "mythbuntu" tag.  It will help attract people who are familiar with MyBuntu to your issue.

Comment: Your log link is broken. Did you follow this http://goo.gl/S54zL